# How to print to next vertical empty cell using Excel::Writer::XLSX

Tags: excel, perl

I am using module [`Excel::Writer::XLSX`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX).

My program will open an Excel file like this

```
    A    B    C 
1   xx
2   xx
3   xx
4
5
```

And in the above example I want to print to A4, A5 and so on

Is this possible?

Currently I am using

```
    $worksheet->write( "a$num", "$key" );
    $num++;
```

but that will always start at a specified point.

Comment: Which module are you using, also `$num ++` is missing a semi colon

Comment: i am using Excel::Writer::XLSX;

Comment: Please update the full code

Comment: *"My program will open an Excel file like this"* If you are using `Excel::Writer::XLSX` then this is impossible. The module cannot load pre-existing Excel files, and is intended for creating them from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that without messing with the internals of the `Excel::Writer::XLSX::Worksheet` object hash

But that shouldn't be a problem. The module can only create Excel files from scratch, so anything that's already in column A is something that you've written there. You just need to keep track of what data has been added

Comment: I see. Mat i ask what module should i be using if i want to open a existing excel file?